# System.Management.ManagementClass thows System.IO.FIleNotFoundException

Tags: c#, .net

The following code throws System.IO.FIleNotFoundException:

```
System.Management.ManagementClass m = new System.Management.ManagementClass("Win32_OperatingSystem");
            DateTime lastBootUpTime = new DateTime();
foreach (System.Management.ManagementObject instance in m.GetInstances()) 
{
  lastBootUpTime = ParseCIM_DATETIME(instance["LastBootUpTime"].ToString());
}
```

The `foreach` line throws the exception. The exception detail below shows that it's in the `GetInstances` method. I've looked at everything I could find about this, but nothing that seems to apply.

This exception occurs repeatedly on a customer PC that has been working successfully on a daily basis since 2014. It's not connected to the internet. I'm informed that there have not been any configuration changes or Windows updates to the PC or the C# program since then. There's a local SQL Server Express database that's updated by the program but that's it.

I don't see how something so static could fail this way. Am I looking at some kind of memory or disk corruption?

[image]

Comment: There is a diagnostic utility from Microsoft which can used to diagnose problems with the WMI service.. have you tried this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ff404265(v%3dmsdn.10)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll have to get access to the machine, one way or another, to be able to run it. I'll see what I can do.